# Difference between Orthic triangle and Pedal triangle

Tags: geometry

Is there any difference between Orthic triangle and Pedal triangle or both both are same ?

Comment: A [pedal triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalTriangle.html) is defined by an arbitrary point. (The vertices of the pedal triangle are where the feet of perpendiculars from that point meet the side-lines of the original triangle.) The [orthic triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthicTriangle.html) is specifically the pedal triangle determined by the original triangle's orthocenter. (I notice that this distinction was provided in a comment to one of your [earlier questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3098798/409). Do you have reason to doubt the veracity of that comment?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Orthic triangle is formed by the feet of the altitudes of a triangle and a pedal triangle is the one in which an arbitrary point is chosen in the plane and then perpendiculars are drawn from this point to the sides of the triangle.These points are joined to form the pedal triangle.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_triangle

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)#Orthic_triangle

https://cut-the-knot.org/triangle/PedalTriangle.shtml